# Returning to Ruby and Rails. Which components should I update before starting a new application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

It's been almost a year since I was writing with Ruby and Rails.  I see there are some new tools, including `rbenv`, and many updates to other tools.

What tools should I update before starting a new application?

I am using a mac with OS X ver 10.9.4

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Jubobs, I'm not recommending particular software here.  This is the second time I have returned to R&R after a hiatus.  Both times I have found it is non-trivial to update and get going again with current tools.  Going through the update process a second time, I wish I had documented the first go-around so I didn't have to figure it all out again.

Comment: I appreciate the intent. The problem is that, if tools continue to evolve so quickly, your question and answer will have little value in a year's time. Stack Overflow encourages long-lasting contributions. That's why http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: A valid point.  Just to counter, These are the same tools that were 'recommended' 4 years ago when I got started with R&R.  Four years isn't bad in terms of longevity softwarewise.

Comment: Fair enough, then `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but here's what worked for me.

In the end, I had to update

- rvm
- bundler
- ruby
- brew
- rails
- port
- xcode-select
- git

I started with

```
rvm get stable
```

... to update the ruby version manager.  Some would advocate switching to rbenv.  My reading indicates I would have to uninstall RVM to make use of rbenv.  I have several older R&R apps and I couldn't be sure how uninstalling rvm would affect my ever returning to maintain those older applications, so I'm sticking with RVM for now.

```
rvm list
```

... showed me which versions of Ruby I have installed.

```
gem install bundler
```

... updated bundler.

```
rvm install 2.1.2
```

... got me the latest version of Ruby at the time of this writing.

```
rvm list
```

... showed me a list of the installed version of Ruby, which I was currently using, and which was the default version.

```
rvm --default use 2.1.2
```

... changed the default version of ruby that I would be using.

```
rvm list
```

... [paranoid] just to confirm the changes.

```
gem install rails
```

... got me the latest version of rails

```
which rails
```

... [paranoid] just to confirm the latest Rails is associated with the latest Ruby

```
sudo brew update
```

... so packages could be built when bundling a new Rails app.  Without this, `bundle install` was failing when creating a new Rails app.

```
rails new myNewRailsApp
```

... created my new Rails app.

```
git version
```

... showed me which version of git I was using.  To upgrade git, I had to upgrade macports and xcode command line tools.

```
xcode-select --install
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install git +svn +doc +bash_completion +gitweb
```

... updated to the latest version of git.